# ExtJS - How can I have multiple components as parents?

Tags: javascript, extjs

First of all, the ExtJS version I'm using is **version 4.2**.

I have a parent component that has multiple children (let's say there's 3 children) that extend from it and therefore modify it.

I now wish to have a new component that will have to pass through one of the other 3 children (it can be any of them) and finally that one child that the new component called, would call the parent.

It's a bit difficult to explain this scenario so to better visualize it, it would be something like this:

NewComponent_| > ChildComponent1 > | ParentComponent
______________| > ChildComponent2 > |
______________| > ChildComponent3 > |

The parent component is a simple popup that the children modify.
The new component is also intended to modify the parent popup however it can't prevent the children to modify it as well.

If I just had one child component, I would simply extend it in the new component and that's it but because I have multiple I'm not really sure what the most appropriate course of action should be.

I thought about trying something like dynamically extending a given child, I'm not sure if that would work.
Also, is there something like multiple parents in Ext? I'm a relative newbie so I really don't know.

Any help would be appreciated and if you need further clarification please say so.

Comment: When you say component, do you mean instance of a class or their definition extends from the parent?  If the latter, are you asking if Ext JS does multiple inheritance?

Comment: I don't know if this helps to better understand it but imagine that one of the children has to pass through another child after it has executed.
Every child extends from the parent, yes

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pass through."  Is it supposed to have some logic from child 1 or what?  Can you create a sketch Fiddle for us please?

Comment: By "pass through" I mean that child1 has to execute its changes to the parent view but child2 also has to execute its changes as well. One after the other. 
For example, child1 makes a combobox become visible and then child2 makes a textfield mandatory. 
I can't have everything in a single child because there might be times where only one of them is executed.
I don't really know how to create a fiddle, sorry. I'm quite new with all this...

Comment: It's actually quite simple to make a Fiddle... very similar to JSFiddle.  Go to https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor, log in/create account in upper right, then select which version of the framework, add your code in the editor, and then click the Run button on the left.  Don't forget to click Save at the end of all of it, so you get a unique link to share with us.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rethink your structure.
First, you cannot change/set class inheritance dynamically. But I think your problem is simpler than it seems.
If I got it right, you have a parent window (modal) that holds some fields or information. If you call any of the three child classes, it overrides/extends that parent, which means you can forget about it. Now you are only dealing with the selected child class.
I guess you have some kind of a view on the base level, a grid or a panel, that then invokes on a - let's say - click event that child class.
So I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
Ext.define('App.ParentModal', {...});
Ext.define('App.Child1', {
    extend: 'App.ParentModal',
    ...
});
Ext.define('App.MyPanel', {
    ...
    items:[
        {
           xtype: 'button',
           handler: function() {
               if (condition1) {
                   Ext.create('App.Child1');
                   // call child1 that modifies parent the way you want
                   return;
               }
               if (condition2) {
                   Ext.create('App.Child2');
                   // call child2 that modifies parent the way you want
                   return;
               }
           }
        }
    ],
    ...
});
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: Yes, the parent popup has some fields that the children modify. 
Having one child selected through its xtype, I have to add extra modifications that will add to the child's existing modifications.
So I'm not actually choosing which child I want to modify the parent, what I really want is for the new panel to add an additional modification and then call the selected child so that it can execute normally.

Comment: Or let's say I have 10 children and after I have executed one of them I have to execute some other given child.
My problem is that both children also call the parent view so maybe that couldn't be the way to do it right?

Comment: Yes, the children share and can modify the parent simultaneously. My suggestion would be to separate logic from layout even more. You could define small components with many reusable components you call on different actions. Extjs is flexible in that matter. The parent should maybe just define the core view or the frame.